# Android PDF reader from scratch

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

I know it sounds ambitious but our client requires a PDF Reader of his own with some selected functionalities. Can anyone guide me to some good tutorials for paving the way to start this development?

I guess I need to clear some pdf basics and start from scratch OR i would be happy if there is any library which i can use directly and only modify the controls at my will.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of specific Android implementation, I really can't advise you there, I'm afraid.

However, there is a lot of PDF viewing software available that is open-source which would allow you to see the underlying code to learn from.

One example is [PDFedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/), which is also an editor, but there are loads on SourceForge or Google Code you could have a look at.

[This Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Multi-platform) has a list of multi-platform development libraries which could help you. There is also a bunch of PDF software, much of which is open-source. Perhaps you could find a simplistic one and have a look at how it parses PDFs.

Comment: thanx a lot T3Roar... this is enough for me to start at it... the reply was quick and perfect i must say... may god bless u...

Comment: but the main thing which i want is a simple pdf reader... and if possible some tutorial guidance about wat exactly pdf rendering is... anyways will wait for some suitable guidance.. till then m trying the way T3Roar told...

Comment: That's my pleasure. The simplest one I have found is Evince, which is a viewer for the Linux Gnome desktop environment: http://projects.gnome.org/evince/. The source is here: http://live.gnome.org/Evince/GettingEvince . It's in C, though. You mentioned rendering, which is another issue entirely. I heard from somebody who wrote a PDF viewer that the most difficult part is parsing since the format is so strange