# Pdf Reader Android

Tags: android

I want write an application which shows an PDF with some other content on it, like Video and image.

Generically I want shows an pdf with some other View on it.
I am concern about PDF, I read some article which explaine how to show an PDF but I want show an PDF with some other stuff.

Do you recommend me some solution or a right way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can render a PDF into your own View (and not launch a 3rd party Activity), you can just wrap that view into a FrameLayout, and draw whatever you want on top of it.

Comment: How can I that? Could you get me a link at some article which cover this topic?

Comment: I would like read some stuff about how render a PDF on a View

Comment: For FrameLayout, maybe read this:
http://www.itgalary.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=1016
For a PDF View, maybe read up on this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947517/android-pdf-reader-from-scratch