# how to develop a pdf reader in android

Tags: android, pdf

we desperately want to develop a pdf reader.we searched for api ,but got java apis which are 
written using applets and swings.how can we run that on android.Or can anybody suggest any
pdf reader api for android.we are stuck in this and cant go forward to complete our app.if
anyone has the source code for that please share .any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey read this discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947517/android-pdf-reader-from-scratch

Answer (score 3):

Get PDF API from either [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/org/broncho/pdfreader) or [this](http://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/andpdf/trunk/AndroidPdfViewer/src/com/sun/)

Comment: Too bad that in the first link, the issue of a missing class has not been solved yet (PdfImageReader.java), making this API difficult to adapt.

Comment: Did you use any of these APIs?

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin not really but these were the only good API's during that time.

Answer (score 2):

Because develop an PDF reader for Android is not really simple, so I suggest you read this PDF file online by Google Docs Reader

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Mobi](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/). Very powerful and fast PDF viewer. Very easy to integrate and use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at qoppas pdf viewer

Comment: it does not work. It gets stuck on loading!

Answer (score 0):

You missed Solo PDF reader, the best one in market. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lrmobilabs.pdfreader&hl=en As we can see 5000+ downloads in 2 weeks. Best PDF Reader for your android device, and Its Free. Contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

[**MuPDF**](http://mupdf.com/).

It's Open Source, dual-licensed: your choice -- either pick GPL v3 or a commercial license. (If you are familiar with [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html), the lightweight PDF- and XPS- viewer for Windows: internally that one is driven by MuPDF...)