# How can i view pdf in android without pdf Application in device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

i want to view pdf file from internet..can anyone tell me how can i view??

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This code For view Online PDF without Using PDF of Application

mWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://your_link/634128127095123576.pdf");

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Please view this answer for more details: [how to develop a pdf reader in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617391/how-to-develop-a-pdf-reader-in-android/5617419#5617419)

Answer (score 0):

But please be aware that webview does create some extra threads like Cookie Manager and history manager , it might just increase your memory foot print a bit.  I saw this behaviour when i looked at threads created in Eclipse ADT plugin