# PdfReader in Android

Tags: android

I have to develop an application which reads pdf file in pdf format and only pdf file should be read in the application.I wanted to know one more thing is it possible to use itext.jar for 
the android application.

Answer (score 3):

Developing an PDF reader for Android is not really simple, so I suggest you read this PDF file online by Google Docs Reader

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 String pdf = "http://www.example.com/example.pdf";//url to pdf file
 webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

This may not be the thing you want, but still hope it helps you someday.

However some Android PDF APIs are http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/org/broncho/pdfreader and http://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/andpdf/trunk/AndroidPdfViewer/src/com/sun/

You can also look at an SO discussion on the same problem [Android PDF reader from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947517/android-pdf-reader-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the opensource PDF readers (eg: XPDF) and compile it for Android.